# String lines sorting by Shell Sort

Tags: java, sorting

I have a text file of 50 string lines of varying length and content. I need to read the file and sort in ascending order. Sorting condition: the number of words in a sentence that start from the letter "a".

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String token1 = "";
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("E:\\text.txt"));

    List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();
    inFile1.useDelimiter(". ");

    while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
       token1 = inFile1.nextLine();
       temps.add(token1);
    }
    inFile1.close();

    String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < tempsArray.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(tempsArray[i]);
    }

    int cnt = 0; //number of words in the string line
    for (int i=0; i<tempsArray.length; i++) {
        int k=0; //number of words that start from the letter "а"
        System.out.println("Line № = " + i);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(tempsArray[i]);           
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            cnt++;
            String s= st.nextToken();
            if (s.charAt(0)=='a') {                    
                k++;               
            }             
        }
        System.out.println("Number of words = " + cnt);
        cnt=0;
        System.out.println("Number of words 'а' = " + k);  
    }       
}
```

I use `Map` as Kau advise me. But `Map` use unique keys. But my **K** can have same values and `Map` can't find an appropriate string element. What other `Сollection` сan I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you already have the algorithm for shell short to sort an array of integers. Let the method be `shellSort(int[] a)`.
What you can do is create a map with key as ***k*** and value as the string representing the line. At the same time we'll create an array of integers that holds all ***k*** . Then call the method `shellSort` on the array of ***k*** values. Then read back from the sorted array, look in the map using the array elements as keys. Fetch the corresponding map values (which are the lines) and put them back one by one in `tempsArray` which should finally have all the lines sorted in the desired way. 
Below is the code (untested) just to give an idea.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
   String token1 = "";
   Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("E:\\text.txt"));

   List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();
   inFile1.useDelimiter(". ");

   while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
     token1 = inFile1.nextLine();
     temps.add(token1);
   }
   inFile1.close();

   String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);
   for (int i = 0; i < tempsArray.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(tempsArray[i]);
   }

   int cnt = 0; //number of words in the string line
   Map<Integer, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
   int[] countArr = new int[tempsArray.length];
   for (int i=0; i<tempsArray.length; i++) {
       int k=0; //number of words that start from the letter "а"
       System.out.println("Line № = " + i);
       StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(tempsArray[i]);           
       while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
          cnt++;
          String s= st.nextToken();
          if (s.charAt(0)=='a') {                    
             k++;               
          }             
       }
       countArr[i] = k;
       List<String> listOfLines = myMap.get(k);
       if(listOfLines  == null){
          listOfLines = new ArrayList<String>();
          listOfLines.add(tempsArray[i]);
          myMap.put(k, listOfLines);
       } else{
          listOfLines.add(tempsArray[i]);
       }
       System.out.println("Number of words = " + cnt);
       cnt=0;
       System.out.println("Number of words 'а' = " + k);  
    }
    //Call shellsort here on the array of k values
    shellSort(countArr);
    List<String> sortedListOfLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<countArr.length; i++){
       List<String> lineList = myMap.get(countArr[i]);
       if(lineList != null){
          sortedListOfLines.addAll(lineList);
          lineList = null;
          myMap.put(countArr[i], lineList);
       }
    }       
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks!

Comment: While getting from the map use `myMap.get(countArr[i])` instead of `myMap.get(i)`. There was a mistake in the original answer that I had posted. I have corrected it.

Comment: Oh, If there are two identical K, Map can not find the appropriate line, and dublicate one line of the two.

Comment: You can use `Map<int, List<String>>` instead. For each K insert into the map with K as key and the line into the corresponding `List<String>`. So if there are multiple K values which are same the corresponding map value will be a list of Strings. You will have to do some additional logic to check if the key exists or not. Create a new List and insert the first line if key does not exist in the map already. If it does then retrieve existing List and insert current line into it. Ofcourse logic for retrieving from map and placing in `tempsArray` will also change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But how to do it?) This must be done after **k** sorting?

Comment: **K** exists always, but its value can be = 0.

Comment: I have updated the answer accordingly to use `Map<Integer, List<String>>`

Comment: Sorry, that line might be wrong. I have corrected it out. Basically checking if k exists in the map. If not (which means `listOfLines` will be null as the map's get method will return null) then create a new list and insert into the map. If k already exists in the map then just get the corresponding list of Strings and add the new line into it.

Comment: You will have to iterate through `sortedListOfLines` and print out the sorted lines. That part is not in the code. You can figure it out yourself.

Comment: I used this `String[] finalArray = sortedListOfLines.toArray(new String[0]);
 for (int m = 0; m < finalArray.length; m++) {
            System.out.println(finalArray[m]);
        }` But result is not well)

Comment: what does the result look like?